# Loading data Issue In hive from hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am trying to load the table in hive from hdfs. I have following data mentioned below , Please help me what Delimeters I can use.

```
104001;LOCAL CARD;LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) - TDFS;;;CANADA;CA;CAN;124
104002;LOCAL CARD;LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) - TDFS;;;CANADA;CA;CAN;124
104003;LOCAL CARD;LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) - TDFS;;;CANADA;CA;CAN;124
104004;LOCAL CARD;LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) - TDFS;;;CANADA;CA;CAN;124
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking into your data-sets, **";"** is field delimiter. So your sample HQL query for external table in hive may look like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename
(
col1 INT,
col2 STRING,
col3 STRING,
col4 STRING,
col5 STRING,
col6 STRING,
col7 STRING,
col8 STRING,
col9 INT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LOCATION '/user/username/input/';
```

Assumption: your input file is at location **/user/username/input/** in HDFS.

Please modify the above `create` statement according to your need.

Hope this helps you!!!

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename
(
col1 INT,
col2 STRING,
col3 STRING,
col4 STRING,
col5 STRING,
col6 STRING,
col7 STRING,
col8 STRING,
col9 INT
)
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '\073'
stoed as textfile;

Comment: I used above command to load the table but because my table do not contains any data in some columns I am getting "" (double quotes) I want null in results.

Comment: null means I want that column to be empty

Comment: @Rani: That is another problem, the above problem is solved I think...you have to raise another question